# override Asp.net Identity MVC5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I dont know asp.net identity work with EF, but I can override to I use Nhibernate.

currently I use custom roles by using filter in my project, I do not need to use anotations roles = "admin", because these roles are customized.
In asp.net identity will custom roles, or work the same way?

Anyone have a example?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement ASP.NET Identity using Nhibernate. You just have to implement the Identity core interfaces using NHibernate. Following post explains how you can create your custom storage provider http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/extensibility/overview-of-custom-storage-providers-for-aspnet-identity

Comment: Here's a worked example, although it doesn't use roles: https://github.com/MartinEden/NHibernate.AspNet.Identity.Example